# Taking user input to add as prefix to filenames

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

I am trying to create a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) which adds a user input string as a prefix to all the files in the folder.

It is on [windows-7](/questions/tagged/windows-7)

```
@echo off
SET /p Input=Enter prefix wanted ie "1906_0516_ORD_TGT5_": 
Echo You entered: "%Input%"
Pause
for %a in (*.*) do ren "%a" "%Input%%a"


Echo Successfully added %Input% to files.
Pause
```

Nothing happens!

Comment: In a batch file, you need to double up the percent characters, **`%`**, for your metavariables, i.e. `for %%a in (*.*) do ren "%%a" "%Input%%%a"`. I would also suggest you either perform some sort of validation of the user input, as some characters are disallowed in filenames etc.

Comment: Enter prefix wanted ie "1906_0516_ORD_TGT5_": 89_
You entered: "89_"
Press any key to continue . . .
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

That is is the error i am getting.  I am new to this just cant get it to work...

Comment: I don't know if this is a reply to my comment or something that should be in your question, but it looks as if you're expecting to be able to change the name of a file that is already open, which as you can imagine would prove difficult, hence the error message you're receiving. If you think about it logically, it  looks as if the batch  file itself could be in the same directory that you're changing all files names in, so you may want to filter it out, `for %%a in (*.*) do if /i not "%%a"=="%~nx0" ren "%%a" "%Input%%%a"`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a batch file you need two % symbols in front of your A variable.

```
@echo off
SET /p Input=Enter prefix wanted ie "1906_0516_ORD_TGT5_": 
Echo You entered: "%Input%"
Pause
for %%a in (*.*) do ren "%%a" "%Input%%%a"


Echo Successfully added %Input% to files.
Pause
```

If you were running it just inside a cmd window manually, not using a batch file then you just use 1 % instead of two.